# Factoring polynomials over a power series ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, power-series

Could anyone tell me why $g(x, y) = x^3 - y^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb C[[x]][y]$ while $f(x, y) = x^3 - x^2 + y^2$ is not?

Comment: What is C{x}? {}

Comment: Since you accepted an answer assuming that $\mathbb C\{x\}$ is $\mathbb C[[x]]$, I think this is what you meant, although as far as I know $\mathbb C\{x\}$ denotes the ring of convergent power series; see [here](http://books.google.ro/books?id=azS2ktxrz3EC&pg=PA1376&lpg=PA1376&dq=ring+of+convergent+power+series&source=bl&ots=MZdFWpvvmK&sig=Wycg8esoCGub5sWHPnkUyIcEjr4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=9nHxUKS1KoOYtQax9YDQBw&ved=0CDcQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=ring%20of%20convergent%20power%20series&f=false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I supposing you mean the ring $\mathbf C[[x]][y]$ of polynomials in$~y$ over power series in$~x$. A non-trivial decomposition of those polynomials, made monic in $y$, would require finding in $\mathbf C[[x]]$ a square root of the negated constant term (coefficient of $y^0$) in both cases. Now $x^3$ cannot have a square root because it has odd valuation. However $x^2-x^3$ has valuation $2$, and a square root would be $x$ times $\sqrt{1-x}$, where the latter square root exists in $\mathbf C[[x]]$ by Newton's binomial formula
$$
  (1-x)^\frac12 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}k(-x)^k.
$$

Comment: Does everything you said also apply to $\mathbb{C}[[x]][[y]] = \mathbb{C}[[x, y]]$? Also wen you talk about valuations, what valuation function are you using? And why does $x$ having odd valuation imply it can't have a square root?

Comment: @Anakhand Irreducible monic polynomials in some ring $D[Y]$ over an integral domain $D$ will still be irreducible in $D[[Y]]$, and this applies here with $D=\mathbf{C}[[X]$, so yes, the question of reducibility is the same in $\mathbf{C}[[X,Y]]$. The valuation in $\mathbf{C}[[X]$ is the standard discrete valuation: the degree of the lowest non-zero term in the power series.

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a reference for "irreducible monic polynomial is also irreducible as power series"?

Comment: It seems [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4821567/326036) is a counterexample to what you stated. Perhaps I misunderstood, or it holds in under some extra assumptions on $D$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming C{x} means the power series ring in $x$ over the complex numbers,

$$f(x,y) = y^2 + x^3 - x^2 = y^2 - (x^2 - x^3) = y^2 - x^2(1-x) = (y - x \sqrt{1-x})(y + x \sqrt{1-x})$$ and $\sqrt{1-x}$ can be expanded as a power series is $x$.  Therefore $f$ is reducible.