# Is a monic irreducible polynomial also irreducible as a power series?

Tags: commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

The observation in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/509295/326036) and [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276194/factoring-polynomials-over-a-power-series-ring/276201?noredirect=1#comment10259396_276201) suggest the following:

> If $R$ is a domain and $f \in R[x]$ is monic and not a unit in $R[[x]]$, then if $f$ is irreducible in $R[x]$ it is also irreducible in $R[[x]]$.

Is this true, and if so how do we prove it? It doesn't seem obvious.

The statement when $R$ is a field seems trivial, since if $f$ is not a unit as a power series it is always reducible, since it has a zero constant term and so it can be factored as some power of $x$ times another polynomial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is false, e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/124378/242) shows the linear polynomial $\,ab+x\,$ is reducible in $R[[x]]$ if $\,a,b\neq 0\,$ are
comaximal nonunits, giving an explicit factorization via a [Catalan series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) $f(x)\in\Bbb Z[[x]],\,$ e.g.

$$\begin{eqnarray}{} 6+ x\, &=&\   (3 - x\:\!f(x))\ \  (2 + x\:\!f(x)) \\[0.5em]
&=&\ \dfrac{5\!-\! \sqrt{1\!-\!4\:\!x}}{2}\,\ \dfrac{5\! +\! \sqrt{1\!-\!4\:\!x}}{2}\\
\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$

It is not difficult to construct algorithms for irreducibility testing and factorization in the UFD $R[[x]]$ over a PID $R,\,$ e.g. see  J. Elliot: [Factoring formal power series over principal ideal domains.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.4860)

Comment: I assume here $R = \mathbb{Z}$? If so, the Catalan series have rational coefficients, right? So is this actually a decomposition in $\mathbb{Z}[[X]]$?

Comment: @Anakhand  The Catalan series $\,f(x)\in \Bbb Z[[x]]$ has integer coef's since it is the generating function of the [Catalan integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) sequence $\,c_n = \frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}.\,$ Thus $\,f(6x)\in\Bbb Z[[x]],\,$ so both factors are in $\Bbb Z[[x]]$